# Passing a custom java security policy file to surefire maven test fails, results in access control error for everything

Tags: java, maven, security, surefire

I'm trying to pass a custom security policy file to surefire to run some tests.  (Specifically, I'm adding classes in java.lang to test a profiler and I want permission to define classes in there.)

I'm not sure if my problem is with the security policy, or with the args I'm passing to surefire.

As per maven docs [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html), I have this plugin configuration:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <argLine>-Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy==java.policy</argLine>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

I've tried file:// paths to the file and other variations.

**Note** the `==` syntax on `-Djava.security.policy==java.policy` is correct, according to [this oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html)

> If you use
>
> java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy==someURL SomeApp
>   (**note the double equals**) then just the specified policy file will be used; all the ones indicated in the security properties file will be ignored.

Here is my security policy file:

```
grant codeBase "file:${{java.ext.dirs}}/*" {
        permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

grant {
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "defineClassInPackage.java.lang";
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
    permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks";
};
```

If I don't specify the policy args, I get an AccessControlError trying to define a class in java.lang, as expected.

If I add the policy args, it is as if I wiped out all grant policies, the tests fail on simply accessing a file - I imagine it is failing on the first access control it attempts:

`java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/Users/me/myproj/target/surefire/surefire_03237249516701375492tmp" "read")`

update:  I tried even with a simple main class without maven/surefire and I still get this error.  I think security policy might be ignored for java.* because in SecureClassLoader there is this bit of code:

```
    if ((name != null) && name.startsWith("java.")) {
        throw new SecurityException
            ("Prohibited package name: " +
             name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf('.')));
    }
```

I also tried editting the JDK's java.policy file in JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security and it still doesn't work.